# Search dataset field (date) for specific custom date. Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, date, dataset

I have a small problem two days now.

I have a combobox (is the month as integer example 3), a textbox (is the year as example 2020) and the day I pick from the code.

This is my code:

```
Dim result() As DataRow
 Dim CurrentMonthDays As Int16 = DateTime.DaysInMonth(CInt(textBoxYear.Text), comboBoxMonth.Text))
 Dim rIndex As Int32

       For d As Integer = 1 To CurrentMonthDays                     
  Dim Date As New Date(textBoxYear.Text, CInt(comboBoxMonth.Text), d)


   result = DataSet.Tables("Thetable").Select("Name= '" & name & "'" &
                                             "AND " & "Date = '" & Date & "'")

                    For Each dr As DataRow In result
                        rIndex = dr.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dr)
                    Next dr

                    If (result.Length > 0) Then
                        do something                 
                    Else
                       do nothing                  
                    End If

                Next d
```

I try to many options but some throw exceptions about are not a valid date or not recognized as string e.t.c
The options that not have an exception and work OK in my PC (the PC I create the code) not working in other, it throws the "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String".

I change the " ' " to " # " and ofc not working, I try to convert the date to string or string to date and the problem is a turnaround.

As I see the database store the date as 1-Mar-2020, I add the records as 1/3/2020. I think that this not matter but...

I have my application work with

```
Dim GreekCulture As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("el-GR")
```

I try to convert it before I search for invariant culture but nothing changes.

The last thing I done is:

```
 Dim Date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(d & "-" & comboBoxMonth.Text & "-" & textBoxYear.Text, "d-M-yyyy", New DateTimeFormatInfo)


 result = DataSet.Tables("TheTable").Select("Name= '" & Name & "'" & "AND " & "Date = #" & Date & "#")
```

Throw exception "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How I must convert the date from string to a date which select command accepts
or how I can rephrase the select command to work for dates?

I hope is not confusing and any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: *As i see the database store the date as 1-Mar-2020* - this might be misdirection. Dates should be stored in date/datetime/time stamp columns in databases and they are NOT stored with any particular format. They're most often stored numerically; any format you see is done by your query tool

Comment: Perhaps your life would be simpler if you just use a dedicated date picker control like DateTimePicker. It would also be good to know what your overall goal is because this seems like a very hard work way of doing something l- I get the feeling this code could be a lot simpler if only I knew what it was trying to do

Comment: @CaiusJard Maybe i see it wrong, if i go to add a record in database table and press 1/3/2020 it auto convert it like 1-Mar-2020. How is stored after that i don't know :).I can't add a Datetime picker.. i have many labels that present a date to a name, when i add text to the label i want to add the record with the name, the date and the text. After i want to reload the label with that record.

Comment: Dates don't have a format! People have date formats, dates are just moments in time. When you type 2000-01-01 it becomes a date, probably a decimal number of the count of days and fractions of days after some epoch, and when your query tool gets it back out of the db and shows it to you it renders it as 1-Jan-2000 but if it showed me it would be January 1, 2000 (because that's how I set my region settings)

Comment: Still very confused as to what your overall goal is

Comment: @CaiusJard Sorry about that, i want the select command to work to other pc too. All my application working fine until i run it at other pc with same net framework, sql, windows system.

Comment: I wouldn't use the Select command; I would search the datatable for a datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be easier to use LINQ for this. For example:

```
Dim n = "John";
Dim d = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1)

Dim rows = datatable.AsQueryable().Where(Function(ro) DirectCast(ro("date"), DateTime) = d AndAlso DirectCast(ro("name"), String) )
```

If you use strongly typed datatables this code would be far less messy:

```
dataTable.AsQueryable().Where(Function(ro) ro.Date = d AndAlso ro.Name = n)
```

If you want to use a datetime in a Select expression you should wrap the date in # and format it according to the invariant culture

```
Dim selStr = $"[Name] = '{n}' and [Date] = #{d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}#"
Dim rows = datatable.Select(selStr)
```

I wouldn't recommend it because it is relying on a round trip from a date d, to a string, then back to a date, but do also take note that using string interpolation has cleaned up the code considerably!

---

As a final note, consider avoiding such basic column names as "date" and "name" because names like this often conflict with database or.net type names (names of classes) meaning they have to be escaped or quoted

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have a little trouble with those solutions to add them in my code. True are more clean that way and sure i will check if i can adapt it inside. I use the select command with #d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)# and work like a charm, even i think i had try it before.  For the data names i use other, just here to make it easier to understand (i think).Thanks again